# display month names as column names in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I want to display year and month names as column names between two dates inside my procedure as below

```
year    jan      Feb  ......Dec
----    -----   -----       -----
2016    val1       val2     val3
2017    val4       val5    val6
```

some one help me to do this

Comment: Provide some sample table data.

Comment: values are number of days within the month

Comment: This is called *pivoting.* Knowing that may help you do more research on how to do it. It's a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL, sad to say.

Comment: someone help me i am stuck with this

Comment: @HariPriya Provide some sample data set

Comment: i  need this kind of output between two dates.I have no dataset

Comment: @HariPriya you just want to generate the days in months in year 2016 and 2017 if i understand your question correctly.. check mine answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this if i understand you question correctly to generate the desired resultset.
`TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY.... + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` makes it possible to calculate the days within a month. 
Please note that months have to be right in every `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2016-01-01', '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Jan'` line and it should work.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   '2016' AS YEAR
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2016-01-01', '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Jan'
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2016-02-01', '2016-02-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Feb'
 ...
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2016-12-01', '2016-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Dec'

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
   '2017' AS YEAR
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Jan'
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2017-02-01', '2017-02-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Feb'
 ...
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2017-12-01', '2017-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Dec'
```

**Result**

```
year       Jan     Feb     Dec  
------  ------  ------  --------
2016        31      29        31
2017        31      28        31
```

Or this query makes it eazier to add a new year and less code duplication.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   years.year
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CONCAT(years.year, '-01-01'), CONCAT(years.year, '-01-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Jan'
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CONCAT(years.year, '-02-01'), CONCAT(years.year, '-02-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Feb'
 ...
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CONCAT(years.year, '-12-01'), CONCAT(years.year, '-12-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'Dec'
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
   '2016' AS YEAR

  UNION 
  ALL

  SELECT 
    '2017' AS YEAR
)
 AS years
```

**Result**

```
year       Jan     Feb     Dec  
------  ------  ------  --------
2016        31      29        31
2017        31      28        31
```